Podman - pgadmin4 permission denied when volume mounting
I'm trying to create a podman run script that rungs dpage/pgadmin4 but it can't create the volume mount
i run the following
podman run -d --name pgadmin \
    --network=host \
    -v "$PGADMINDATA":/var/lib/pgadmin:z \
    -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=$USERNAME \
    -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD \
    -e PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=$PORT \
    --user 5050:5050 \
    dpage/pgadmin4:8.12.0

what i've tried:
added --user 5050:5050
ran it with the :z flag
checked if podman is rootless
podman info | grep rootlesstrue
checked that the id in the container is correct
/pgadmin4 $ id
uid=5050(pgadmin) gid=5050(5050)
changed owner of the directory on the host machine
sudo chown -R 5050:5050 data &&
sudo chmod -R 775 data
verified that it works
ls -la
4 drwxrwxr-x 2   5050   5050 4096 Oct  6 12:19 data
still getting the error
ERROR  : Failed to create the directory /var/lib/pgadmin/sessions:
           [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/var/lib/pgadmin/sessions'

i run this on ubuntu 22 in wsl 2 on windows 11

z only takes care of the SELinux context, you also need U to handle user id mapping.
The error you're getting is a regular permission error: Failed to create the directory /var/lib/pgadmin/sessions.
In a rootless podman setup your user id gets mapped to root inside the container.  User 5050 in the container can't write to directories owned by root. Chowning it to 5050 on the host doesn't make in 5050 in the container. The correct uid to set is your subuid + 5050 - 1. It is found with:
podman info -f "{{ json .Host.IDMappings }}"

But adding ,U to the mount options will do that for you.
podman run -d --name pgadmin \
    --network=host \
    -v "$PGADMINDATA":/var/lib/pgadmin:z,U \
    -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_EMAIL=$USERNAME \
    -e PGADMIN_DEFAULT_PASSWORD=$PASSWORD \
    -e PGADMIN_LISTEN_PORT=$PORT \
    --user 5050:5050 \
    dpage/pgadmin4:8.12.0

